# How do I count the occurance of a string per file in a directory?

Tags: bash, grep

`grep -G '{string}' *. | wc -l`  Gives me the TOTAL count of the `{string}` in the entire directory. And on the other had `wc -l *.` gives me the count of each line per file but not count per file for the `{string}` of my interest. I am looking for something of a combination of the two, where I can count the occurrence of a `{string}` per file separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) option you need is `-c`:

> -c
>
> Write only a count of selected lines to standard output.

---

If you have nested directory in which you like to search :

use [find](/questions/tagged/find) + [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) :

```
find /your_dir -type f -exec grep -cF '{string}' {} +
```

Or if `GNU Grep` is avaible to you (or any other implementation of [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) which supports `-r`) to do a recursive search:

```
grep -rcF '{string}' your_dir
```

If the directory does not hold subdirectory inside, a simple:

```
grep -cF '{string}' your_dir/*
```

will work.

---

Note also that `-G` (`GNU Grep` specific) enables `BRE` engine which is the default choices and which does not handle `ERE` tag like `{` (if not escaped). Consider to use `-F` options to force [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) to search for simple string or to disable regex metacharcter interpolations when not needed.

Comment: 'grep -rcF '{string}' your_dir' was it, short and accurate, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`grep`'s option `-c` prints a count of the selected lines per file.

```
grep -c '{string}' *.
```

(Option `-G` (basic regular expression) is redundant as this is the default.)

---

With the example files

`file1`

```
foo
bar
baz
foo
bar
```

`file2`

```
foo
bar
baz
foo
bar
foo
foo
bar
bar foo
baz
foo
bar
```

I get this result:

```
$ fgrep -c foo file*
file1:2
file2:6
```

If your file name pattern matches only one file, `grep` will not print the file name. To avoid this you can use option `-H` if you have GNU `grep`.

```
grep -cH '{string}' *.
```

(Adding `/dev/null` instead of the non-standard option `-H` would show the count 0 for this additional file.)